# ValueError: too many values to unpack for zip of python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, plot, zip, valueerror, doc2vec

I want to show documents and words of doc2vec model with t-SNE in different color. I wrote the following code in python2.7. But I got error. I have not used t-SNE and plot in python till now.

```
modelfile='/home/fl/models/Robust/dimention500/my_model.doc2vec'
wordNum=10000
docNum=1000
words_vec = []
words_label = []
docs_vec = []
docs_label = []
all_vec = []

model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec.load(modelfile)
w2v = model.wv.vocab
d2v = model.docvecs

lengthVoc=len(w2v)
ids=[None]*wordNum
for i in range(10000):
    ids[i]=random.randint(1,lengthVoc)
for i, word in enumerate(w2v.keys()):
    if i in ids:
            all_vec.append(model[word])
            words_vec.append(model[word])    
for j, doc in enumerate(d2v.doctags.keys()):
    if j in docids:
            all_vec.append(d2v[doc])
            docs_vec.append(d2v[doc])

words = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(numpy.array(words_vec))
docs = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(numpy.array(docs_vec))
all_dw = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(numpy.array(all_vec))


g1=words
g2=docs
data = (g1, g2)
colors = ("red", "blue")
groups = ("word", "document") 

for data, color, group in zip(data, colors, groups):
    x, y = data
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=color, edgecolors='none', label=group)     
plt.title('Robust04')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 91, in <module>
x, y = data
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

When I changed the following part of my code to `plt.scatter(all_dw[:, 0], all_dw[:, 1])`, it shows the figure but all words and documents have same color.

```
for data, color, group in zip(data, colors, groups):
    x, y = data
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=color, edgecolors='none', label=group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what `zip(data, color, groups)` returns – it's likely not what you expect.

Specifically, its 1st item is going to have in its first index `g1` – not a `(g1, g2)` tuple. And `g1` is just `words`. So your problem line is essentially:

```
x, y = words
```

If there are more than 2 items in `words`, you'll get the `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. (Check `words.shape` – it's likely `(10000, 2)`.)

If `data` is itself a list of many `x, y` pairs – eg `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]` – and you need a separate list of all x-values and all y-values, you can actually use `zip()` again, on `data` *unpacked* as a parameter-list using the `*` prefix operator. For example:

```
x, y = zip(*data)
```

(A transpose of `data` might work equivalently too, such as: `data.T`.)